# Limit application logins for a user using Spring/JSF

Tags: spring

Here is what I want to do, please tell me if it is possible.

- User A logs in with username: `user1`  // no problem
- User B logs in with username: `user1` // I want to check if user1 is logged in, if yes I will show a modal confirmation dialog asking the user if they want to close all previous connections.

I am using Spring's `maximumSessions` bean property to limit the logged sessions for the user, but I want to show a confirmation dialog before logging in for the second time, please tell me how can I do that, or maybe Spring has a built-in functionality that achieves that.

Thanks

Comment: have a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372311/how-to-invalidate-an-user-session-when-he-logs-twice-with-the-same-credentials/2372990#2372990

Comment: This question as it stands is not java, jsf. For maximum sessions also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20953904/spring-security-max-session-allowed. And User A and User B do not share sessions, at least not http sessions...